# Excel COUNTIFS Statement Error

Tags: countif

I need to exclude rows in which the cells within 2 columns are the same - for example:

B2=NAME, C2=INFORMATION

B4=NAME, C4=INFORMATION

In the example above, I only want to count the row the first time, not the second. I'm using a COUNTIF statement but getting a 1 for all rows, even when the cells match like the example above.

=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$2,B196,$D$2:$D$2,D196)>1,0,1)

Comment: Can you explain what your formula is supposed to do? You want a result in one cell with a total, or you want some result next to each row (since you say "but getting a 1 for all rows")? You basically want to count the number of rows where B and C (together) are unique?

Answer (score 0):

### Count Unique Rows

To get the count of unique combinations of `NAME` and `INFORMATION` from a range in column B and column C, I would use  [COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) and [UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e), not [COUNTIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

1. Create an array by joining the values in `B2:B7` to those in `C2:C7` using the operator `&`
2. Apply the [UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) function to remove duplicates from the array
3. Use [COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) to count the remaining array values

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B2:B7&C2:C7))
```

[image]

### Blank Rows

- If the range contains any blank rows, then first [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) the array for `<>""` to remove them
- If the range contains one or more non-blank rows that you want to exclude, such as the column headings in `B1:C1`, add their row number as a [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) condition
- combining [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) conditions using `AND` is done with an asterisk `*`

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(
   FILTER(B:B&C:C,
         (B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B)<>1))))
```

[image]